# Why is my 5V linear regulator giving out 6.34V?

Tags: power-supply, linear-regulator

**Update :-(:**

I tested the pinouts of the IC with a multi meter and the connections are fine. Then I discovered I had done a very stupid mistake and connected Vout where Vin should have been connected. I corrected it and now there is no difference between input and output.
So problem discovered, and is my board toast?

---

I bought [this](https://robu.in/product/ams1117-5v-step-power-supply-module/). Its supposed to give out 5V DC. My input is 7.13V DC. Why is it giving out 6.34V?

Power is coming from a 12V adaptor, stepped down to 7.13V via a [buck convertor](https://robu.in/product/lm2596s-dc-dc-buck-converter-power-supply/) before the linear regulator so that the AMS1117 doesn't have to do too heavy lifting. I'd expect it to then give 5V.

The images say on the PCB its a YL-46, whatever that means, but the thing which came had HW-122 printed instead.

Here's a pic of what I've got.
[image: Actual part]

Comment: We really can't know with the info you give. Either it has a manufacturing error or you are using it incorrectly. For any better answer, add more info.

Comment: @Justme question edited. I have soldered everything, no wrong connections done, checked again.

Comment: More info added.

Comment: The IC is what is important. Is it an AMS1117 , and how doe the PCB layout compare to what is shown there. || Do connections to IC match what my answer's pinouts say they should be?

Comment: Side note: don’t ever buy from someone who uses “104” and “106” instead of component designators. Lack of either ballast resistor or just the know-how to adjust the LED resistor to provide it in the first place.

Comment: Note that AMS1117 Vin specification varies with supplier. Some have 18V and 30V Vin abs max ratings (see data sheet refs in my answer) BUT some have 12V abs-max Vin ratings. The one in your cited as says 12.5V in large red letters. If you have allowed even a sniff of >= 12V on Vin the regulator may be dead.  || I've seen the 12V max spec cited on low cost Arduino clones from China. Interestingly the Chinese LCSC supplied data sheet says 30V.

Comment: Can you verify that your meter is working properly by checking against another meter or measuring some known voltage such as the 5V on a USB port?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany yes the MM is working ok, I use it everyday and the 12V from the adaptor is showing fine.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I only connected the AMS1117 to the buck convertor after setting the BC to 7.13V. I have pasted an image of the actual part in the question. There is nothing on the back side, its completely blank, no traces even.

Comment: BTW, I use this buck convertor module in many of my stuff, it ussually has an LED, but this one is not lighting up. Maybe the LED is bad? What I am sure is that the output of the BC is 7.13V. The BC LED problem could not be to blame, could it?

Comment: This question got closed, I am surprised why. What more details could I have provided here? It doesn't make sense. Maybe my board is faulty, but surely my question isn't. Who decides to close questions?

Comment: @JohnSnow I had nothing to do with your question being closed. || So far you have failed to address my major important question despite it being the basis of my original answer and my having specifically asked it twice. it **MAY** be what is wrong. It may not. You can check it in a minute and report back. || I provided the pin outs for the regulator. Using an ohm-meter: Does regulator Vout Vin Ground - connect to PCB Vin Vout Ground correctly? || Also -  ensure MINIMUM 10 mA load as others have noted. ||Please report back.

Comment: John: Question closing is done by any 3 site members with enough reputation to do so. Despite you having 3 answers and varioous people helping 3 members have decided to close the question. || If you answer my question it may be enough to reopen your question. || Also chck for shorts and opens between points not expected. These are unlikely BUT it should take you a minute or few to do so. || If you need advice please ask, || Question can be flagged for reopening - use reopen button & flag button under question to comment to moderators.  (I'm a moderator).

Comment: The minimum 10 mA load in on the OUTPUT. R = V / I = 5/0.010 = 500 Ohms (or lower). If you do not have a 500 Ohms (std value = 470 Ohms) resistor then use 2 x 1K in parallel. Or any resistor smaller than 500 Ohms. || If you use say 1 100 Ohm resistor dissipation will be Power = V^2/R = 5 x 5 / 100 = 0.25 Watt. R's between 100 and 500 will give lower dissipations.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon just tested and replied to your answer. Also flagged this question for moderator intervention.

Comment: _"my board toast?"_ Most probably yes. For future reference, using the same colors for all cables increases the risk of connecting it backwards or reversing polarity. Use color coding when possible.

Comment: See reverse polarity protection addition to my nswer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Absolute maximum Vin.

The AMS1117 Vin specification varies with supplier.
Some have 18V and 30V Vin abs max ratings (see data sheet refs in my answer) BUT some have 12V abs-max Vin ratings.

The one in your cited ad says 12.5V in large red letters.
If you have allowed even a sniff of >= 12V on Vin the regulator may be dead.

I've seen the 12V max spec cited on low cost Arduino clones from China. Interestingly the Chinese LCSC supplied data sheet says 30V.

---

2. PCB fault?

The PCB MAY have been incorrectly made.
Looking at the two versions in the ad that you cited it's not  clear that the regulator connects correctly. This seems unlikely but is easily checked. Check viaually and/or use an ohm-meter to see if the IC pins connect to Vin, Vout, Gnd as expcted.  see diagrams below for probably AMS1117 pinout.

Is the IC on your board an AMS1117?

This is the pinout shown in several datasheets that I found online.
Left to right, tab up, Ground Vout Vin - as shown in red at the bottom of the image below.

The two images are from the page you cited BUT show different PCBs.
What are the actual connection to Vout and Vin on your PCB.

If these are in fact in erro a little 'surgery' with a scalpel or similar will allow correction.

[image]

AMS1117 datasheet [here](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/2001081204_Shikues-AMS1117-1-2_C475600.pdf)

[image]

---

and [here](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/UTD%20Semi%20PDFs/AMS1117.pdf)

[image]

3. Minimum load

It has been suggested that the AMS1117 requires a minimum  load of 2 mA typical, 10 mA max.   This is true of the adjustable versions. It may not be true of the fixed voltage versions. Adding a 10 mA load when testing would do no harm.

---

**REVERSE POLARITY PROTECTION:**

The circuit below uses one P Channel MOSFET and one resistor to provide protction against reverse power supply polarity.
The PFET has the drain and source swapped compared to more normal use.  This means that the FET's body diode conducts when the polarity is correct - not something that is wanted when the FET is used as an on/off switch.

The FET is turned fully on when the gate is pulled adequately negative relative to the source by R1.  This bypasses the body diode and FET on resistances in the milliohm range are achievable at modest cost.

When the supply is reversed the body diode does not conduct, and R1 now pulls the gate positive relative to the source. As it is a P Channel FET this turns it off.

If Vin is near or above  Vgate-source-max an additional resistor can be added to reduce the gate-source voltage to a safe level.

I added this system to a battery powered product I designed of which several hundred thousand were built. The Chinese manufacturers preferred this method over the use of mechanical polarity protection.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgRohr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: @winny  I suggest that your comment better belongs on your answer or on the question. || 106 means 10 uF and 104 means 0.1 uF in this context. Thos values suggest that the designer was at least half competent so my "wrong PCB": answer may be wrong :-)

Comment: I don't see this being incorrect. Can you describe or show which part you think is incorrect? To be fair, the tracks are hidden under the component so I can't verify it being correct either.

Comment: You're going to have to be more explicit about where you think the error is. The PCB looks fine to me, at least as far as not being able to see what's under the components or the other side (which I'm guessing is just all ground plane).

Comment: @DaveTweed  I may well be wrong. Looking at the PCB I cannot be sure that some tracks join where they might. As two different PCB layouts are shown in the ad it is not certain which if either is his. I added a comment on his question re testing this - I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: Yes, half-competent is a nice term. I should use it more often in the office. :-D

Comment: I posted the actual component pic, I cannot see a fault. Can you?

Comment: @JohnSnow  Check regulator connections with ohm-meter. Regulator tab up, viewed from top of board - as per photos in my answer. || . Ground should be left hand pin Vout should be middle pin. Vin should be right hand pin. Is that how it is connected

Comment: The original Arduino Nano uses an LM1117 rather than AMS1117 which is limited to 15V input absolute maximum so they spec the official Arduino Nano input as 7-12VDC. There are also thermal limitations to think about if the user's project draws power from the 5V rail so spec'ing a 12V limit even if the regulator is capable of more makes some sense. FWIW the AMS1117 datasheet from AMS says 15V abs max.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon sorry for the late response, I was kind of away, I tested the pinouts of the IC with a multi meter and the connections are fine. Then I discovered I had done a very stupid mistake and connected Vout where Vin should have been connected. I corrected it and now there is no difference between input and output. So problem discovered, and is my board toast?

Comment: @JohnSnow  Probbly dead, but you can buy replacement regulator ICs from eg China (or India - I see your cited site has them). and that package is reasonably easy  to solder if you haven't had much practice. || I see you bought from an Indian site - are you in India? . || I checked your site --> About the same cost for 5 x  AMS1117 [here](https://robu.in/product/ams1117-1-8v-1a-sot-223-voltage-regulator-ic-pack-of-5-ics/) as for your whole module :-).

Comment: @RussellMcMahon yes I am writing from India. I'll just get another module, they are really cheap. BTW, can I solder some additions from outside so even if I accidently attach the wrong end it would still live?

Comment: @JohnSnow  A consistent colour scheme and a set of rules to follow is probably adequate. | I tend to use red/black for output +/- and eg yellow/black  for input +/- IF the ground is common to input and output - which it is in your case.  || You COULD add a diode in the output +ve BUT even a Schottky drops maybe 0.3V - which destroys your regulated 5V supply accuracy. || You can add a reverse diode ACROSS Vin and ground. This clamps supply to ground with reveresd supply - adding a fuse upstream of the diode blows the fuse if Vin is reversed. || There is a cct with a FET to prevent rvrsd supply.

Comment: @JohnSnow  Interest only: Where in India? Are you a resident or ... ? || I've been to Chennai, Pune, New Delhi, Agra, Mumbai.  I'd love to visit again 'sometime'.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I am from the North, close to where the Himalayas start, small town (you wouldn't have heard of it, and I'd like to stay anonymous, its the internet  ). You should visit this part of the country, the northern mountains, just not in the Monsoon though when there's plenty of floods and landslides going on each year now because of the global warming. Ping me if you ever hit the road north of Delhi, I'd give you best guide tips.

Comment: @JohnSnow 35 countries so far. Id love to spend more time in India but quite likely never will (and many other places). My wife worked in Pune for 3 months.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148321/discussion-between-john-snow-and-russell-mcmahon).

Answer (score 5):

It all looks okay to me. The AMS1117 is not guaranteed to be stable with a ceramic capacitor load. They recommend a 22uF tantalum capacitor in the [datasheet](http://www.advanced-monolithic.com/pdf/ds1117.pdf).

That 'rule' is broken in many low-cost modules such as the one you have, and I've not heard of it causing an issue, however I don't think we can rule it out.

If you have a 22uF or thereabouts tantalum capacitor you could try replacing the output '106' capacitor (taking care as to polarity- tantalum caps usually have the + side marked rather than the negative as on aluminum electrolytic caps). Or replace it with an aluminum electrolytic of 20uF or greater.

---

Another (perhaps more likely) possibility is that you might have damaged the regulator accidentally by connecting the input in reverse, even for an instant. Using two red wires for both + and - makes that an easier accident to happen. There is no reverse voltage protection on this chip.  The upstream buck regulator would limit the current so the damage would not be as visually (or olfactibly, or audibly) evident as if the module was (say) connected the wrong way across a car battery.

Answer (score 2):

1117 requires a minimum load of 10 mA to regulate. It’s unclear if your module provides that or not.

[image]

Try hooking up a 470 ohm resistor on the output and check again.

Comment: Can I try 1K? Might not have 470. And this is to go between +ve and -ve, right? I sound like a novice because I am.

Comment: Sure. Or two in series. Or stack on top of the 1k to the LED to increase the current.

Comment: @winny Minimum load usually refers to the adjustable part to allow for reference pin current. I do not know which datasheet you are using but eg [this one](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/2001081204_Shikues-AMS1117-1-2_C475600.pdf) notes that the current is for the ...-ADJ part. What does your note 5 say?

Comment: soldered 1K between output +ve and output GND, nothing changed

Comment: check out my most recent edit to the question also

Comment: 1 k is too low, but something should have changed as it’s not digital on-off. Junk part? Measure the ADJ pin.

Comment: The old LM317 also had a minimum load current of 10mA or 5,A for the more expensive LM117. The output voltage rises if there is no minimum load. Maybe the burnt out LED was the 10mA load?